# Can I always assume that a function that does not return a Promise or an Observable is synchronous functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to assume that a function that does not return a Promise or an 
Observable is synchronous functions in JavaScript. If not how to know whether a function is sync or a-sync.

Comment: No, you can't. `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise. `addEventListener` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: Consider also every function in continuation passing style (i.e. the callbacks promises mostly replace).

Comment: Why do you want to know if a function is sync or async?

Comment: The statement that is very next to the function call depends on the value of the function return value. If it is a sync fn I can call await on it to wait until the very next line is executed.

Comment: If it is a synchronous function, you do not use await - it just naturally returns the answer.  If it is an asynchronous function _and_ has the async keyword before it (so returns a Promise of the result type), then you can await on the result, and it will 'act' like a synchronous method (except it will allow other tasks to be completed while whatever asynchronous work is pending inside it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to determine whether a method (that does not return a promise or observable) is synchronous or not synchronous.  I could take a regular synchronous method and add a call to an asynchronous function to it.  From the outside, it looks the same - but now it is queueing up (triggering, whatever your favorite terminology) some asynchronous work.  As mentioned above, another key function signature is one that takes a callback handler - if it does, it is likely (though, to be pedantic, not necessarily) asynchronous.  But assuming a function does none of those things, you can't really know.

You may not care about that asynchronicity - you may only care whether what you *think* the method is doing completes before it returns or not, and that may be obvious from its return type.  For instance `addTwoNumbers(a: number, b: number): number` clearly is synchronous in terms of returning the result, but, as I mentioned above, it could have spawned some asynchronous work (e.g. logging something to a file) and you'd never know from the function signature.

Comment: Oh! Ok.. I got it. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know whether the Array functions in JS are async or not?

Comment: I believe they all are, but if you've got questions about any particular one, you can just look at the documentation.  If it returns the kind of thing you think should be the result, then it is likely synchronous.  Most standard functions in Javascript are not "sneaky" in whether they are synchronous or not.

Answer (score 1):

Promises are a relatively recent addition to Javascript, but there have been asynchronous functions for much longer. The older asynchronous functions do not return a promise. Examples:

- `XMLHttpRequest.send`
- `setTimeout`
- `addEventListener`

If a function takes a callback function as an argument, and the function's return value depends the result of that callback, then the function has to be synchronous. Async functions can never return the result of the callback, since it's called after the function returns.

So, for instance, all the array-processing functions like `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`, must be synchronous because they return arrays whose contents are dependent on the callback function.

Comment: I would like to know whether the Array functions in JS are async or not?

Comment: You mean things like `map` and `forEach()`? They're synchronous, since they return the result immediately.

Comment: If a function's return type is the type of the result you expect, then it is likely synchronous.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Is there is any standard way to check if a fn async or not?